# Flutter 3 Auto - Suggestion / Completion Not Work

Tags: flutter

after upgrading to flutter 3.0.0 / 3.0.1, suggestion or autocomplete code not work, can't call initState completion, or setState suggestion :

[image]

what i have tried to do to fix :

- flutter upgrade
- restart my computer
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter pub upgrade

and still not work.

here my flutter doctor
[image]

dart sdk setting & flutter sdk setting :
[image]
[image]

flutter plugin & dart plugin :
[image]

i did try to downgrade flutter to 2.10.5, and the auto-suggestion works without any problems.
what's wrong with flutter 3? any steps needed to upgrade that I missed?
please help me, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the dart analysis server -

- Navigate to Dart Analysis tab at bottom.
- Click Restart Icon (red colored icon on top left corner of Dart Analysis Window)
- Wait for dart analysis to finish.

After these close and restart the android studio.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i did what you suggested, but still not working. delete .dartServer, disable plugin, reinstall android studio, problem still persist

Comment: Actually your auto completion is not working just for setState. So, the plugins are working fine then. The problem is elsewhere and actually it happens often with me but gets okie on its own.

Comment: From what I've noticed, it seems to be a general problem, when I create a class and then extend it, I don't get suggestions for properties, as with iniState, setState, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too and I solved it by pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) to show Override methods and I think the next dart update will solve the problem.